# Show the differentiability of function without using $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition

Tags: calculus

Let $U\subseteq\mathbb R$ is an open set and
\begin{align}
f:\ U&\longrightarrow\mathbb R\times\{0\}
\\ x&\longmapsto f(x)=(x,0)
\end{align}

It is easy to prove that $f$ is continuously differentiable by $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition by chosing $\delta = \varepsilon$. Could anyone hint me some other way to show this briefly ? Thank you.

Comment: Isn’t it equivalent for a function to be countinuously differentiable and for it to admit continuous partial derivatives ? Note that it is not true for non continuous differentiability

Comment: $f$ is smooth, as (the restriction to $U$ of) a linear map.

Comment: do you mean $f$ is smooth since it is a linear map on $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: I do not get why do you need $\varepsilon -\delta$ method. In your case it is easy to see that the derivative is constant and equal $(1,0).$ In order to verify that you compute the limit when $x\to x_0$ of $${(x,0)-(x_0,0)-(x-x_0)(1,0)\over x-x_0}$$ The expression is equal $0$ so its limit is equal $0.$